# How to define the number of columns to be exported from excel to MS access table using access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2013

I am importing an excel worksheet TableName.Test to access table and the functionality is working fine. However, all the empty columns are also getting imported crossing the number of maximum access table column. Please let me know how can I export only the first 10 columns from excel to access.

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
'Dim strXls As String
'strXls = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "BI_DataBase.xls"
 tableName = "MiddleTable"
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True, "Test!"
 Exit Sub
```

Comment: In my Test worksheet, there are only 10 columns, I would like to export only 10 columns, but currently 255 columns with empty fields are getting copied. Please let me know how can I eliminate the export of empty columns

Comment: You are importing or exporting, confusing?

Comment: I am importing data from excel to Access. So I am using Access VBA. When I run the above code, instead of first 10 columns 255 columns are being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `[Range]` argument for your columns. Use `"Test!A:J"` means import columns A to J from sheet `Test`. When you are not specifying columns then it is taking maximum column capacity of [MS-Access table which is limit to 255](https://www.easysoft.com/blog/access-column-limit.html#:%7E:text=13%20June%202019-,A%20Workaround%20for%20the%20Access%20255%20Columns%20Limit,the%20first%20255%20columns%20only.).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.